# PuppeteerJS - how can I scrape text content from a td element based on the text of the adjacent td?

Tags: element, puppeteer, scrape

I am attempting to scrape a link from a td cell adjacent to another td labeling the type or description of the link using puppeteer. There are no classes or id distinguishing these td cells other than the text content

```
         <tr>
            <td scope="row">1</td>
            <td scope="row">10-Q</td>
            <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1065280/000106528018000538/nflx-093018x10qxdoc.htm">nflx-093018x10qxdoc.htm</a></td>
            <td scope="row">10-Q</td>
            <td scope="row">1339833</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="blueRow">
            <td scope="row">2</td>
            <td scope="row">EXHIBIT 31.1</td>
            <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1065280/000106528018000538/nflx311_q32018.htm">nflx311_q32018.htm</a></td>
            <td scope="row">EX-31.1</td>
            <td scope="row">14914</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td scope="row">3</td>
            <td scope="row">EXHIBIT 31.2</td>
            <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1065280/000106528018000538/nflx312_q32018.htm">nflx312_q32018.htm</a></td>
            <td scope="row">EX-31.2</td>
            <td scope="row">14553</td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="blueRow">
            <td scope="row">4</td>
            <td scope="row">EXHIBIT 32.1</td>
            <td scope="row"><a href="/Archives/edgar/data/1065280/000106528018000538/nflx321_q32018.htm">nflx321_q32018.htm</a></td>
            <td scope="row">EX-32.1</td>
            <td scope="row">12406</td>
         </tr>
```

the link after td containing '10Q'

Comment: Can you add HTML of a sample td element you are trying to scrape?

Answer (score 3):

#### XPath expressions

This is where [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) expression are great:

```
//td[contains(., '10-Q')]/following-sibling::td[1]/a[1]
```

This XPath expression queries for a `td` element containing the text *10-Q*. Then it will take the following `td` element and return the first link (`a`) inside. Alternatively, you could use `//td[text()='10-Q']/` in the beginning, if you don't just want the element to contain the text, but to exactly match it.

#### Usage within puppeteer

To get the element with puppeteer, use the [`page.$x`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) function. To extract information (like `href`) from the queried node, use [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

Putting all together, the code looks like this:

```js
const [linkHandle] = await page.$x("//td[contains(., '10-Q')]/following-sibling::td[1]/a[1]");
const address = await page.evaluate(link => link.href, linkHandle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with vanila javascript,

```
// find all tr elements
[...document.querySelectorAll('tr')]

 // check which one of them includes the word
 .find(e=>e.innerText.includes('10-Q'))

 // get the link inside
 .querySelector('a')
```

[image]

With puppeteer `$eval`, this can be simplified,

```
page.$$eval('tr', eachTr=> eachTr.find(e=>e.innerText.includes('10-Q')).querySelector('a'))
```

Or `page.evaluate`,

```
page.evaluate(()=> {
 // find all tr elements
    return [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')]

     // check which one of them includes the word
     .find(e=>e.innerText.includes('10-Q'))

     // get the link inside
     .querySelector('a')

     // do whatever you want to do with this
     .href
})
```

Readable solution.